# VS2010 Debugger Not Responding

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a large website that is comprised of multiple applications. We are still using web forms. All of the applications are in a common directory that serves as the root directory in my localhost. The site was originally built in 2005 on 3.5 but has been migrated to 2010 still running on 3.5 (2.0). My problem is that my debugger will run once. After I stop debugging I cannot run the debugger again - it just hangs. My locals and watch windows open but do not populate and the browser never opens. Any suggestions? We are running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: I have the same problem here on up-to-date Win Server 2008 R2 x64, so this issue is still alive.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but with silverlight - it appeared after I changed my .vssettings file

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I do not have a permanent solution, but here's how I get around it at the moment:
- start without debugging (Ctrl-F5)
- Debug | Attach to Process
- Select the code type(s) to debug
- Select the aspnet_wp process
- click Attach

I will keep searching for a permanent solution...